# Why does cron job not work when using a script?

Tags: command-line, cron

The command `wall -n "Hello, World!"` works when I put it manually into crontab. But if I make an executable with this command and call it using cron, it does not work. I have tested the script and it works and the path of the script is included in `~/.profile`.

Answer (score 1):

In cron you have to use the full path to the script:

```
/path/to/script.sh
```